# How can I access mongodb from purescript?

Tags: mongodb, purescript

How can I access mongodb from purescript?

the only package I found was purescript-node-mongodb
but it looks outdated, and it doesn't install with spago

is there any other recommendation?

if not, should I use nodejs driver?

Comment: I've not used mongo from PS yet but it seems that this lib was updated for _purs-0.12.0_: https://github.com/SimonRichardson/purescript-node-mongodb/commits/master . Do you have any compilation problems on _purs-0.13.8_ with it? It should not be hard to fix them I think. Could you please provide a bit more info I would be more than happy to help.

Comment: No worries, thank you for you reply

Found this fork where he fixed the issues, so with this one I could make it work: https://github.com/j-nava/purescript-mongo

cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this fork that solves the problem:

https://github.com/j-nava/purescript-mongo

it was as easy as:

```
queryEmail :: String -> Query User
queryEmail email = Q.by { email: Q.eq email }

findUserEmail email db = do
  col <- Mongo.collection "users" db
  users <- Mongo.find (queryEmail email) defaultFindOptions col
  pure case users of
    [] -> Nothing
    arr -> arr # Array.head
```